# How often can I expect egg-laying animals to lay eggs?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I captured several war Jabberers and cave crocodiles from goblin sieges; I am trying to breed them, by chaining them right next to a nest box. Since then, none of them occupied the nest boxes.

Am I doing something wrong? How often would a "normal" egg-laying animal lay eggs? Can such an animal claim a nest box while on a chain? Technically, the chain is supposed to only limit movement range, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have more ordinary, domestic poultry that you've successfully bred? There may be a problem with breeding exotic beasts unknown to your civilization.

Comment: @PaulZ surely the animals can figure it out without any help from the dwarves.

Comment: @PaulZ just now i saw a blue peahen has claimed a nest box, so yes. I did the same thing -tied the hen with a chain next to the nest box

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal egg-layers lay eggs roughly once per season.

However, and this is the point you're having problems with:

War animals never lay eggs; or, if they are not egglayers, never breed.

I've never had occasion to find out if animals find a nest box while on a chain, but I suppose they should.

But again; captured war animals will not breed.

Ever.

Comment: do you mean animals trained for war or animals captured from invaders in general?

Comment: I mean war animals captured from invaders. Untrained animals captured from invaders should breed normally, more or less.

Comment: Ok, so the cave crocodiles might work? Since they are not trained war animals? Also, i guess selling the war animals to a merchant and rebuying it is not a feasible workaround, is it?

Comment: I hereby confirm that this semms to hold for all animals captured from invaders. The cave crocodiles did not breed either.

Comment: I suspect this may have been done to fix the behavior in some older versions, where war animals brought by invaders would, if the invasion lasted long enough, sometimes give birth and then immediately start fighting their own offspring. Dunno why Toady decided to do it this way, though, rather than just making the offspring inherit their mother's civ affiliation.